# Text field make editable, not editable using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am using display tag for creating tables and using jquery to make a textfield editable and remove readonly property.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $(".makeEditable").click(function(){
        $('input:text').removeAttr("readonly");    
    });
    $(".makeNonEditable").click(function(){
        $('input:text').attr("readonly", "readonly");    
    });               
})
</script>
```

Here is the code for table and column with textfield

```
<display:table name="loadData" style="float:left;">
    <display:column title="User Defined" class="colId">
    <input type="text" value= "" name="userdefined" size="10" readonly="readonly"/>
    </display:column>
</display:table>
```

I have created a button to make it editable...

```
<input type="button" value="Make Editable" class="makeEditable" />
```

I dont know why but its not working...no action happen

Comment: Your code is working fine see a working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/w3yep/ hope it helps `:)` I have put in the non editable button as well for you so that you can test!

Comment: Haven't you forgotten to add jquery lib before your script? :) `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>` and everything works fine.

Comment: its there....<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: yes its working fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/w3yep/...i dont know why but not even javascript work on my code...its still bugging me

Comment: Off topic but...  Do you have more than one button of class makeEditable and makeNonEditable?   Otherwise, it would be better to use ids and not classes to identify the elements (for one thing it would run faster).

Answer (score 3):

For html input text field:

```
<input id="name" type="text">
```

You can use readonly property-

```
$("#name").prop("readonly",true);
```

This will make text field uneditable.

To make it editable :

```
$("#name").prop("readonly",false);
```

Answer (score 1):

// for disabled i.e. cannot highlight value or change
disabled="disabled"

// for readonly i.e. can highlight value but not change
readonly="readonly"
jQuery to make the change to the element (substitute disabled for readonly in the following for setting readonly attribute).

$('#someId').attr("disabled","disabled") 
or

$('#someId').attr("disabled", true)